# Does SerialPort follow kind of FIFO?

Tags: multithreading, serial-port

For example, I've got 2 threads, each sending a request to the same serial. Will the response of them follow the same order of the request? Or chances are the response of the latter request might come first?

The serial reading process has no way to know the response it's receiving is for which request. So I want to make sure the response order to handle the reading process.

Thanks.

Comment: If the two threads writes in the order of A B into the serial port, computer attached on the other end of the serial port will read A and then B. If that computer also response following this order, then you're right; otherwise, not. You need a session layer if you need to differentiate responses of different requests.

Comment: Depending on the platform, they might not even be atomic! I'd wrap the serial in something with exclusive access which accepts and returns complete "messages" for client threads.

Comment: The other end is real serial device, not a computer. So?

Comment: What @KenCheung says.  In the general case, it would be best if the serial protocol APU's had a sequence number, or other ID, so that responses can always be tied back up to requests.  That covers the case of races on locks, the peer being able to handle overlapped requests/responses etc.